# Add large number of arcs through Transactional Cypher HTTP endpoint

Tags: http, neo4j, cypher

I want to add some thousand arcs to a Neo4j 2.3.7 database through the HTTP endpoint.

What would be a reasonably fast way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If all the new "relationships" (which is the correct neo4j term for "arcs") will have the same relationship type (say, "BAR"), then you make a single parameterized Cypher query to add that number of relationships.

In this example, I assume that the value passed as the `data` parameter is a collection similar to this:

```
[
  {a:1, b:2, props: {x: 100, y: "abc", z: 500}},
  {a:3, b:2, props: {x: 123, y: "bar", z: 99}},
  ...
]
```

Here is the corresponding query (where `id` is the sample node property used to identify the unique end nodes of each relationship being created).

```
UNWIND {data} AS d
MATCH (a {id: d.a}), (b {id: d.b})
CREATE (a)-[r:BAR]->(b)
SET r = d.props;
```

Note: If the `a` node and/or the `b` node will always have the same label(s), then the `MATCH` clause should specify the labels and you should also create the corresponding index(es) *(e.g., `CREATE INDEX ON :Foo(id)`)*. This will make the query more performant.